# Determine the pointwise limit of $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider $f_n:[0,2]\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ given by
$$f_n(x)=\left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l 1}
     n^3x^2, & \quad 0<x<1/n;\\
     n^3\left( x-\frac{2}{n}\right)^2, & \quad 1/n \leq x < 2/n;\\
     0, & \quad \text{otherwise}.
   \end{array} \right.$$

Determine the pointwise limit of $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$.

So given $x>0$, we choose any $N>2/x$.

Then $f_n(x)=0$ for $n>N$.

For $x=0$, $f_n(x)=0$ so $f(x)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,2]$.

I'm not sure if my value of $N>2/x$ is correct or if my method is correct.

Comment: Looks good.${}$

Comment: Yes, it's a great job.